# repeat dataframe 1 for each id in data 2 in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, panel, replicate

I have two dataframes:

df1 looks like  with 2273780 other ID's:

```
id 
XIZ92
DA8J0
```

df2 looks like with 29435 other COMR :

```
COMR
9868
9875
1234
```

I want a df3, that replicate all COMR for each ID, like this :

```
id       COMR
XIZ92    9868
XIZ92    9875
XIZ92    1234
DA8J0    9868
DA8J0    9875
DA8J0    1234
```

I am sure that ther is an easy way but can't find my way around it. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try expand.grid? But with that many IDs you will have billions of rows. (2273780*29435 = 66,928,714,300)

Comment: @zx8754 guess that why my computer crushes!

Comment: @zx8754 ok now that I mannaged to seperat my data, it works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. `base::merge`:

   ```r
   merge(dat1, dat2, by = NULL)
   #      id COMR
   # 1 XIZ92 9868
   # 2 DA8J0 9868
   # 3 XIZ92 9875
   # 4 DA8J0 9875
   # 5 XIZ92 1234
   # 6 DA8J0 1234
   ```

   This works like this even if there are multiple columns in either frame.

   (This won't work with `data.table` objects, since `data.table::merge.data.table` requires non-null `by` arguments.)
2. `expand.grid`:

   ```r
   do.call(expand.grid, c(dat1, dat2))
   #      id COMR
   # 1 XIZ92 9868
   # 2 DA8J0 9868
   # 3 XIZ92 9875
   # 4 DA8J0 9875
   # 5 XIZ92 1234
   # 6 DA8J0 1234
   ```

   This works as long as there are exactly one column in each frame; if there are two or more columns, this explodes unnecessarily. Try it!

   ```r
   dat2$ign <- 1
   nrow(do.call(expand.grid, c(dat1, dat2)))
   # [1] 18                             # expecting 6
   ```

Comment: thanks. yes, I have multiple columns and it crashes my R session each time

Comment: ok now that I mannaged to seperat my data, it works perfectly. thanks!